# Ffmpeg HLS conversion error on AWS Lambda - ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert video files into HLS streams on a AWS Lambda. The ffmpeg configuration I have setup works for normal (Non HLS) transcoding, but in case of HLS it throws the following error:

```
stderr:
frame=  341 fps= 84 q=34.0 q=32.0 q=28.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.52 bitrate=N/A speed= 3.1x    
frame=  385 fps= 85 q=34.0 q=31.0 q=27.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.97 bitrate=N/A speed=3.08x    
frame=  433 fps= 86 q=33.0 q=30.0 q=27.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.55 bitrate=N/A speed=3.08x    
[hls @ 0x702c480] Cannot use rename on non file protocol, this may lead to races and temporary partial files
[hls @ 0x702c480] Opening '/tmp/stream_0.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x702c480] Opening '/tmp/stream_1.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x702c480] Opening '/tmp/stream_2.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x702c480] Opening '/tmp/master.m3u8' for writing
ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV
```

And I error thrown by fluent-ffmpeg is this:

```
2023-03-06T10:21:44.555Z    15a0a43b-5e24-42ac-ae72-fe04f0c72a3e    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV",
        "    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:180:22)",
        "    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)",
        "    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)"
    ]
}
```

This is the code I run on AWS Lambda to convert video files into HLS:

```
export const compressToHLS = (sourcePath, outputFolder) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Ffmpeg(sourcePath)
      .complexFilter([
        {
          filter: "split",
          options: "3",
          inputs: "v:0",
          outputs: ["v1", "v2", "v3"],
        },
        {
          filter: "scale",
          options: {
            w: 1280,
            h: 720,
          },
          inputs: "v1",
          outputs: "v1out",
        },
        {
          filter: "scale",
          options: {
            w: 960,
            h: 540,
          },
          inputs: "v2",
          outputs: "v2out",
        },
        {
          filter: "scale",
          options: {
            w: 640,
            h: 360,
          },
          inputs: "v3",
          outputs: "v3out",
        },
      ])
      .outputOptions([
        "-map [v1out]",
        "-c:v:0",
        "libx264",
        "-b:v 3000000",
        "-map [v2out]",
        "-c:v:1",
        "libx264",
        "-b:v 2000000",
        "-map [v3out]",
        "-c:v:2",
        "libx264",
        "-b:v 1000000",
      ])
      .outputOptions([
        "-map a:0",
        "-c:a:0 aac",
        "-b:a:0 96000",
        "-ar 48000",
        "-ac 2",
        "-map a:0",
        "-c:a:1 aac",
        "-b:a:1 96000",
        "-ar 48000",
        "-ac 2",
        "-map a:0",
        "-c:a:2 aac",
        "-b:a:2 96000",
        "-ar 48000",
        "-ac 2",
      ])
      .outputOptions([
        "-f hls",
        "-hls_time 10",
        "-hls_playlist_type vod",
        "-hls_flags independent_segments",
        "-hls_segment_type mpegts",
        `-hls_segment_filename ${outputFolder}/%v_%d.ts`,
        "-master_pl_name master.m3u8",
      ])
      .outputOption("-var_stream_map", "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2")
      .outputOption("-preset veryfast")
      .output(`${outputFolder}/stream_%v.m3u8`)
      .on("start", (cmdline) => console.log(cmdline))
      .on("progress", (progress) => {
        let prog = Math.floor(progress.percent * 10) / 10;
        if (Math.round(prog) % 10 == 0) {
          console.log(`${prog}% complete`);
        }
      })
      .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          console.log("stdout:\n" + stdout);
          console.log("stderr:\n" + stderr);
          reject(err);
        }
      })
      .on("end", () => resolve())
      .run();
  });
```

In this code the sourcePath is usually a presigned URL from S3 (But I have also tried to download a file on /tmp and setting sourcePath as the path to the downloaded file) and outputFolder is `tmpdir()` which is `/tmp`.

I have the lambda settings configured to have 10GB of memory and 10GB of ephemeral storage (the maximum allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a week ago, I encountered the same problem and solved my problem with this method

```
ffmpeg()
     .input(inputFile)
     .complexFilter(`[v:0]split=${split === 0 ? 1 : split + 1}${repeatInput(split)}${repeatResolution(split)}`)
     .addOptions([
                ...mapResolutions(split),
                '-hls_playlist_type event',
                `-hls_key_info_file ${keyInfoPath}${randKeyName}.keyinfo`,
                `-hls_base_url pathFolder/`,
                '-master_pl_name master.m3u8'
     ])
     .addOptions(`-var_stream_map`, repeatStreamMap(split))
     .output(`${hlsPath}file_%v.m3u8`)
     .run()




function repeatInput(num) {
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        str += `[in${i}]`;
    return `${str};`;
}


/**
 * Repeat resolution
 * @param {Number} num
 * @return {string}
 */
function repeatResolution(num) {
    const obj = [
        {w: 480, h: 360},
        {w: 854, h: 480},
        {w: 1280, h: 720},
        {w: 1920, h: 1080}
    ];
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        str += `[in${i}]scale=w=${obj[i].w}:h=${obj[i].h}[out${i}]${num === i ? '' : ';'}`;
    return str;
}


/**
 * Map resolutions
 * @param {Number} num
 * @return {String[]}
 */
function mapResolutions(num) {
    const arr = [];
    const bitrateArr = [
        '1000k',
        '2000k',
        '4000k',
        '6000k'
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        arr.push(`-map [out${i}]`, `-c:v:${i} libx264`, `-b:v:${i} ${bitrateArr[i]}`);

    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        arr.push('-map a:0');

    return arr;
}


/**
 * Repeat stream map
 * @param {Number} num
 * @return {string}
 */
function repeatStreamMap(num) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        arr.push(`v:${i},a:${i}`);
    return arr.join(' ');
}
```

Using the code, I was able to get the desired output through the ffmpeg tool and it works correctly, even I was able to process 4 files of 1 GB at the same time without any error.

Note: The value of split in this pseudo-code helps to output only the resolutions that the video supports. Its value varies from zero to three. By default, ffmpeg is used for all inputs that are written in the option section, output with the corresponding resolutions. If you want to output only the resolutions that the video supports, you need to first get the video resolution type using ffprobe and then create an object with these types.

```
const hlsResolutionsSupported = [
    640,  // 360
    854,  // 480
    1280, // 720
    1920  // 1080
];

const resolutions = metadata.streams[0].width;
let split = hlsResolutionsSupported.indexOf(resolutions);
split = split === -1 ? 0 : split;
```

I hope it was useful

Comment: Your config is working! The only big difference between your config and my config is that `-hls_playlist_type event` instead of `-hls_playlist_type vod` on mine. Could you explain the difference between them if you have a good idea?

Comment: I don't have a detailed explanation on this, but when I used vod to process the video in several different resolutions, the generated ts files were deleted one after another in the m3u8 file until the job was finished, the process repeated itself. And the output of the m3u8 file was only referred to a few ts files, which is one of the reasons in my opinion. But there may be other reasons that I am not aware of

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved the problem by using a lower version of ffmpeg at the url below.

> https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/old-releases/

Current release: 6.0 does not work in my aws lambda.

try to ffmpeg-5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Even with the longest runtime and highest memory setting AWS Lambda is limited to 15m runtime. AWS recommends to have "short" functions executed in the Lambda environment.

SIGSEV is SIGNAL Segfault, which means that there was an unexpected error in the FFMPEG application and it was killed because of it. To find out what ffmpeg's problem is, you would need to debug FFMEG, enable more logging, etc.

AWS recommends to use [AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/) for transcoding tasks.

Comment: I'm aware of Lambda's 15mins runtime, my payload is usually less than 100mb and should be completed in a few minutes.
I'm already transcoding similar payloads with FFMPEG without HLS which works perfectly, but when I try to transcode it to HLS, I face this. And weirdly fluent-ffmpeg shows that the progress is 99% done when this error is thrown